# How Do I Return An IConvertible From A Generic Method If T Has No Parameterless Constructor?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a custom class that reads in a set of key-pair values as objects that implement IConvertible. Instead of writing a host of GetValueAsSomeObjectType methods, I want to write one generic method instead.

I think I've ALMOST got it, but not quite:

```
    public static IConvertible GetSetting<T>(string settingName,
        string settingsFile = null, bool
        ignoreCase = true) where T : IConvertible, new()
    {
        IConvertible t = new T();

        foreach (Setting setting in Settings)
        {
            if ((settingsFile == setting.File || settingsFile == null)
                && (settingName == setting.Name
                   || (ignoreCase == true && (settingName.ToLower() == setting.Name.ToLower()))))
            {
                t = (IConvertible)setting.Value;
                return (T)t.ToType(typeof(T), null);
            }
        }

        return t;
    }
```

Now I seem to be able to do this, which is kind of cool:

```
object KeyName;
bool ValueAsBool = (bool)GetSetting<bool>(nameof(KeyName));
```

However the following results in a syntax error, because string doesn't have a parameterless constructor:

```
string ValueAsString = (string)GetSetting<string>(nameof(KeyName));
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: The error you're getting isn't a syntax error, and shouldn't be saying "syntax error" in the message. Please check what you're really getting. More to the point, I'm really not sure what you're trying to do. You're constructing a `T`, and then converting that to type `T`. What are you hoping to accomplish by this, and what are you hoping for this to do when `T` is `string`? Given that you can't have `new string()`, you can't convert `new string()` to `string` in order to return that.

Comment: I accidentally left out where T : IConvertible, new(), but that's in my code. Fixed.

Comment: So why is the return type `IConvertible`? You probably want `T` so you can avoid the cast. And you don't seem to do anything with the *value* that's presumably somewhere in the `keyPair`, since you are always converting a new instance.

Comment: What you have still cannot compile. You're not returning anything if the `foreach` loop finishes without returning. The compiler will flag that as an error. Meaning this still isn't the code you're actually using, it's some possibly related code, but different enough that it's still not clear what your question is really about.

Comment: To make a long story short, though -- no, you cannot pass `string` for `T`, precisely because it has no parameterless constructor. You'll need a separate `GetKeyPairValueString` method, or pass a `Func<T>` that allows arbitrary creation through a delegate rather than relying on the constructor. Clumsy, but necessary. (And `IConvertible`/`Convert` isn't all it's cracked up to be -- no support for nullable types, for starters.)

Comment: @hvd It should now compile.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert

When I try to return T, I don't seem to be able to do this:

    t.ToString();

Because t is not a type of string. I'm screwing up the code I'm showing here but I'm hoping the general idea is getting across.

Comment: @ZacharyLayne Of course `return T;` won't compile when `T` is a type. Copy and paste the actual code you want to ask about already, and make it clear what it is you're trying to ask.

Comment: @hvd 

Added the actual code I'm trying to deal with.

Comment: And now it's starting to make sense. This also answers my earlier question of why you'd construct a `T` just to convert it to `T`: you're not doing that at all.

Comment: @hvd

I apologize. I'm at work & a bit distracted. The code above grabs the value as a bool correctly, but not anything without a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Given your method definition, the most sensible behaviour to me appears to be to return either a hardcoded `null` or a user-specified fallback value (passed in as an additional parameter) if no setting of the specified name exists. Either way nicely completely avoids the problem of constructing a `T`, allows removing the `new()` constraint, and allows `T` to be `string`.

Even when `new T()` compiles and doesn't throw an exception, constructing a brand new `T` is not necessarily something you can meaningfully do. For a trivial example, if `T` is `bool`, some settings may need a fallback value of `false` whereas others need a fallback value of `true`.

Answer (score 0):

@hvd
I was able to get it to work!

```
    public static T GetSetting<T>(string settingName,
        string settingsFile = null, bool
        ignoreCase = true) where T : IConvertible
    {
        foreach (Setting setting in Settings)
        {
            if ((settingsFile == setting.File || settingsFile == null)
                && (settingName == setting.Name
                   || (ignoreCase == true && (settingName.ToLower() == setting.Name.ToLower()))))
            {
                return convertToType<T>(setting.Value);
            }
        }

        return default(T);
    }


    private static T convertToType<T>(IConvertible value) where T : IConvertible
    {
        return (T)value.ToType(typeof(T), null);
    }

    private object value1;
    public bool Value1AsBool = (bool)SettingsReader.GetSetting<bool>(nameof(value1));
    public String Value1AsString = (string)SettingsReader.GetSetting<string>(nameof(value1));

    private object value2;
    public double Value2AsDouble = (double)SettingsReader.GetSetting<double>(nameof(value2));
    public string Value2AsString = (string)SettingsReader.GetSetting<string>(nameof(value2));
    public int Value2AsInt32 = (int)SettingsReader.GetSetting<int>(nameof(value2));
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you got it to work? What did you have to change?

Comment: @sstan 

I got rid of the new().

Comment: And I see you also managed to change `GetSetting` to return `T`. That probably means you don't need all those casts anymore.

Comment: @sstan That's right! :) I've been using it at work without the casts.